# Julia: How to import a graph from text file (csv with unequal number of 'columns')?

Tags: csv, graph, import, julia

I was wondering if anyone knows of a clean way to import a graph in **Julia** from a text file that is formatted as in the following example (which I shall name "graph.csv"):

```
1,6,7,3
2,5
3,9,8
```

So, the lines have a non-fixed number of entries (>1). If I just use `readdlm()` naively, I get a matrix with empty-string entries:

```
readdlm("graph.csv", ',', '\n')

# 3x4 Array{Any,2}:
#  1.0  6.0  7.0  3.0
#  2.0  5.0   ""   ""
#  3.0  9.0  8.0   ""
```

I have two issues with this. First of, I don't like to use more memory than needed. Second, due to the empty fields, I cannot interpret the rows as integer arrays, i.e. `readdlm("graph.csv", ',', Int, '\n')` doesn't work.

The way I import my graph now uses two steps. First I import each line as a string and then I parse each line for integers:

```
graph_strings = readdlm("graph.csv", '\n')

graph = map(line -> map(parseint, split(line,',')), graph_strings)

# 3x1 Array{Array{Int64,1},2}:
#  [1,6,7,3]
#  [2,5]    
#  [3,9,8]
```

An alternative, more 'Matlabby', way uses an `Any` array:

```
graph_strings = readdlm("graph.csv",'\n')

graph = {map(parseint, split(graph_strings[i],',')) for i=1:length(graph_strings)}

# 3-element Array{Any,1}:
#  [1,6,7,3]
#  [2,5]    
#  [3,9,8]
```

My question is twofold:

**1. Is there a better way of doing this?**

**2. If not, which of the two ways to import described above would be preferable for a large graph?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
graph = map(
  line -> map(int, split(chomp(line), ",")),
  open("graph.csv") |> eachline
)
```

This gives you an `Array{Any, 1}`, though. If you need an `Array{Array{Int, 1}, 1}`:

```
graph = Base.mapfoldl(
  line -> map(int, split(chomp(line), ",")),
  push!,
  Vector{Int}[],
  open("graph.csv") |> eachline
)
```

Comment: @IainDunning, in your answer, shouldn't this be `adjlist = Vector{Int}[]`? (I comment here because I cannot comment on your answer.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `readdlm` is right for this data, its just inherently not tabular.

My approach, which I believe is fairly minimal in memory usage, would be

```
f = open("graph.csv","r")
adjlist = 
while !eof(f)
  push!(adjlist, map(int, split(chomp(readline(f)),",")))
end
close(f)
```

which produces

```
julia> adjlist
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1,6,7,3]
 [2,5]
 [3,9,8]
```